# What is the name of the data structure for and-or-lists (or and-or-trees) and where can I read about it?

Tags: regex, data-structures, regular-language

I recently needed to make a data structure which was a nested list of and/or questions. Since most every interesting thing has been discovered by someone else previously, I’m looking for the name of this data structure. it looks something like this.

‘((a b c) (b d e) (c (a b) (f a)))

The interpretation is I want to find abc or bde or caf or caa or cbf or cba and the list encapsulates that. At the top level each item is or’ed together and sub-lists of the top level are and’ed together and sub-lists of sub-lists are or’ed again sub-lists of those are and’ed and sub-lists of those or’ed ad infinitum.  Note that in my example, all the lists are the same length, in my real application the lists vary in length.

The code to walk such a “tree” is relatively simple, but I’m assuming that there is a name for that type of tree and there is stuff I can read about it.

These lists are equivalent to fixed length regular expressions (which I've seen referred to as "network expressions", but I am particularly interested in this data structure and representation thereof.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

Answer (score 1):

In general (in the very high level of abstraction) it is:
[Context free grammar -Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

If you allow it to be infinitely nested, then it is not a regular expression because of presence of parentheses (left and right should match).

If you consider, that expressions inside parentheses are ordered. I mean that `a and b and c` is equivalent to `(a and b) and c`. You get then [Binary expression tree -Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)

**But for your particular case**, it is probably: [Disjunctive normal form -Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

I am not sure, but my intuition says that it is regular expression again because you have only 2 levels of nesting (1st - for 'or-ed' and 2nd - for 'and-ed' parts)

Comment: The disjunctive normal form link was particularly useful.  I think that these trees are a representation of a subset of that.  The mapping to Karnaugh maps was particularly interesting.  I don't have negations, but otherwise the mapping seems approximately right. It definitely gives me a place to continue my search.

Answer (score 0):

The trees are also a subset of [DAWGS - directed acyclic word graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) and one could construct them the same way.

In my case, I have a very small set that I have built by hand and I don't worry about getting the minimal set, but instead just want something that I can easily write down but deals with the types of simple variations I see.  Basically, I have different ways of finding where I keep my .el files based upon the different directory structures of various OSes I use.  (E.g. when I was working at Google, the /usr/local/emacs/site-lisp directory was actually more like /usr/local/Google/emacs/site-lisp.)

I don't need a full regex, but there are about a dozen variations, some having quite long lists of nested sub-directories (c:\users\cfclark\appData\roaming\emacs.emacs.d or some other awful thing) that I wanted to write down (and then have emacs make an automated search to find the one that is appropriate to this particular installation).   And every time I go to a new job, I can simply add to the list a description of where they are in that setup.

Anyway, as that code has evolved, I found that I had I was doing (nested or's and and's and realized that the structure generalized to the alternating or/and/or/and/... case).  So, my assumption is that someone must have discovered this before.  I had hints of it myself several years ago, but didn't set down to implement it.   The [Disjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) link mpasko256 gave is also particularly relevant.  I don't normalize to that level, I still keep nested and's and or's rather than flattening to 2, but I do have a distinct structure, or's at the top, then and's, then or's....